# How can i stop QThread from repeating function in python PyQt5?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I am using pafy module to download youTube videos, when i click Get quality button it woks perfectly for the fist time, but when try to get quality for another video the function repeated sometimes.

**Get Quality Button  will get the name and quality of videos**

if i use terminate() it will not work for the second time...

my entire code and widget.ui here: https://pastebin.com/0kityt79

look at these pictures you will understand what i mean.

The first time when i click Get Quality

[image]

the second time when i clicked Get Quality

[image]

```py
class KYD(QWidget,myui):

    urlSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(QWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        self.get_quality_btn.clicked.connect(self.getQuality_vdieos)


        self.worker=workers()
        self.mythread=QThread()

    def getQuality_vdieos(self):
        try:
            url=self.Url.text()
            self.worker.moveToThread(self.mythread)
            self.urlSignal.connect(self.worker.qualities)
            self.urlSignal.emit(url) #this will send url to workers class,qualities function

            self.mythread.start()

            self.worker.info.connect(self.information)#this will send the title of the videos to the QTreeView

            self.worker.urlLink.connect(self.insertQulaity)

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    def insertQulaity(self,values):
        try:
            for qualities in values:
                self.chooseQuality.addItem(str(qualities),qualities)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

Class workers(QObject)

    info=pyqtSignal(str)
    urlLink=pyqtsignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def qualities(self, url):
        try:
            if url !='':
                self.source = pafy.new(url)
                self.videos_streams = self.source.videostreams
                self.info.emit(self.source.title) #this will send title to TreeView
                for self.videos in self.videos_streams:
                    size=humanize.naturalsize(self.videos.get_filesize())
                    data=['{}     {}     {}'.format(self.videos.resolution,self.videos.extension,size)]  
                    self.urlLink.emit(data) #this will send quality to Combobox

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Comment: Yekem program ba kurdi la stackoverflow!

Comment: بەراست یەکەم پرۆگرامە ؟ لەم وێبسایتە ،، هەندێکم کردە ئینگلیزی بۆ ئەوەی لێم تێبگەن هههه

Comment: Bale, aw programma la bo ch bakar dini?

Comment: بۆ داونڵۆدکردنی ڤیدیۆی یوتوب ، دەتوانێت پلەی لیستیش داونڵۆد بکا وە بیکات بە صەوت،،  تەنها ڕاهێنان دەکەم بۆ فێربوونە زۆر باش نییە چوونکە ماوەیەکە دەستم پێکردووە ..

Comment: Dast xosh bi Python u PyQt5 zor ba hezin bo software drust krdn. Andazyari computeri?

Comment: سوپاس ،، نەوەڵا معالج طبیعیم ، چارەسەرکاری سرووشتی  لە بێ ئیشیدا خەریکی   پرۆگرامینگم ،، بەڵام زیاتر حەزم لە  پرۆگرامینگە. تۆ  پێدەچێت ئەندازیاری کۆمپیوتەر بیت؟

Comment: Zor basha har sarkawti bi. Mn andazyari sharistanm, bas pewistm ba programming a mnish wa to xom ferkrdya ba kari dinim la bo asan krdini kari rojanam

Comment: هەر سەرکەوتوو بیت ان شاء الله 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the `QThread` part, but rather with the fact that every time you click the button you are adding signal-slot connections between the `workers` and `QYD` objects. Just create all the connections you need in `QYD.__init__` instead of `QYD.getQuality`. Also, you don't have to start the thread, nor move the worker to the thread every time you press the button so you can move all that to `QYD.__init__` as well. So in summary, `QYD` should be something like

```
class KYD(QWidget,myui):

    urlSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(QWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        self.get_quality_btn.clicked.connect(self.getQuality_vdieos)

        self.mythread=QThread()
        self.worker=workers()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.mythread)

        self.worker.info.connect(self.information)
        self.worker.urlLink.connect(self.insertQulaity)
        self.urlSignal.connect(self.worker.qualities)

        self.mythread.start()

    def getQuality_vdieos(self):
        try:
            url=self.Url.text()
            self.urlSignal.emit(url) 
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```